# How to mask multiple values in a String using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex and trying to implement regex for my code.
My code is receiving message String that contains few attribute that I need to mask. Now the Format of message string can be little different and masking attributes could be dynamic.
Here is the example

```
String message1 ="details-\r\n"+
 "pin:testpin\r\n"+
 "pass:test\r\n";
String message2 = "{\"pin\":\"1234\",\"pass\":\"test\"}";
```

Can we write regex that works if I want to mask pin and pass both ?

Comment: Please try [`(pin|pass):(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/GmymA6/7)

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: Is below correct way to use regex? I am new to regex 
message2.replaceAll("(pin|pass):(\w+)", "******") ?

Comment: Use it like `message2.replaceAll("(pin|pass):(\\w+)", "$1: ******")` Escape the `\` in `\w`

Comment: Thanks Mandy.It worked perfectly for message1. I am getting problem with message2 though.I have updated message2 in the  original message.One more qs- Can we have replacement like if pass has 4 char , it should replace by four asterisk and if pass has 7 char , it should replace by 7 asterisk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These regular expressions are looking for `pin` or `pass` surrounded by `"` followed by `:"` and then looking to for closing `"` as soon as possible (`.*?` is non-greedy). The values get the replace by `*`

```
message2 = message2.replaceAll("\\\"pin\\\":\\\".*?\\\"", "\"pin\":\"****\"")
                   .replaceAll("\\\"pass\\\":\\\".*?\\\"", "\"pass\":\"****\"");
```

It has the disadvantage, that `"` may not be part of the values of `pin` or `pass`.

Here's a minimal test:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[]arg) {
    String message2 = "{\"pin\":\"1234\",\"pass\":\"test\"}";
    message2 = message2.replaceAll("\\\"pin\\\":\\\".*?\\\"", "\"pin\":\"****\"")
                       .replaceAll("\\\"pass\\\":\\\".*?\\\"", "\"pass\":\"****\"");
    System.out.print(message2);
  }
}
```

Here's a bigger example with replacing the correct length. There are more things going on here:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[]arg) {
        //more complex
        String message1 ="details-\r\n" + "pin:testpin\r\n" + "pass:test\r\n";
        String regex1 = "(\\r\\npin:)(.*?)(\\r\\npass:)(.*?)(\\r\\n)";
        message1 = Pattern
            .compile(regex1)
            .matcher(message1)
                .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(1) + "*".repeat(mr.group(2).length()) + mr.group(3) + "*".repeat(mr.group(4).length()) + mr.group(5));


        String message2 = "{\"pin\":\"1234\",\"pass\":\"test\"}";
        String regex2 = "(\\\")(pin|pass)(\\\":\\\")(.*?)(\\\")";       
        message2 = Pattern
            .compile(regex2)
            .matcher(message2)
                .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(1) + mr.group(2) + mr.group(3) + "*".repeat(mr.group(4).length()) + mr.group(5));

        System.out.println(message1);
        System.out.println(message2);
    }
}
```

In the bigger example I'm using the replaceAll method with a lambda function in order to replace what's found. I need it in order to know the length of a matched group. That length is then used to create a string consisting of `*` with the length of the input.

Also I added groups in the regular expressions. Groups are parts of the regular expression surrounded by `(` and `)`. Those groups can then be used by the [matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) to more easily modify the input.

Comment: Thanks for your response .Above code works for message2. Can we have some common regex ? I am looking for some common regex code that can work for both message1 and message2.

Comment: I adapted the example in order to also have the correct length of the masked strings. From a security perspective it does not always make sense to let people know, how long the masked string is. A placeholder with a fixed length does not tell other people how long the pin and password really are.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed example.That's exactly what I needed.You are a lifesaver !!